# How can we print the sum of series 1+ 11 +111+........ upto N terms using recursion in C

Tags: c, algorithm, function, recursion

I have tried continuously to print the sum of this series using recursion but ended up returning its nth term only. I know how to print the sum of series using iteration but it has been too hard for me to print its sum using recursion.

After a lot of thinking, I came upto this as the final code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumseries(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The sum of the series is %d",sumseries(n));
}
int sumseries(int n)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum=sum*10+1;
    return (sum+sumseries(n-1));
}
```

Can you help me with this without using the for loop?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: A for-loop doesn't imply that no recursion is used. Your solution isn't the best there is, but it is a solution nonetheless.

Comment: wow how you guys don't let math manipulate you! this is good,

Comment: Maybe, first get the ending number and work backward. If n=4 feed 1111 into your recursion function and keep "loosing" the one's term till the value = 0. Then you know its time to return back.

Comment: the max value for 'n' will be somewhat less than 14 to avoid an integer overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, if you were doing this by hand, how would you do it?

Well, by hand you'd probably write each term down:

```
1 + 11 + 111 + 1111 + 11111 + 111111
```

And then you'd start taking sums: `1 + 11 = 12`, `12 + 111 = 123`, `123 + 1111 = 1234`, etc.

Of course, you could also take the sums going backwards: `111111 + 11111 = 122222`, `122222 + 1111 = 123333`, etc.

In order to attack this with recursion, you'll need to carefully plan out what the function is returning and what its arguments are.

You have, in this problem, two things you need to calculate: the actual series terms (1, 11, 111, 1111, etc) and the sum of those terms. As is clear by the name of your function, you intend `sumseries` to be returning the sums of the series.

Now, you seem to have in hand already a way to make the next term from the current term (multiply by 10 and add 1), but that isn't helping with the recursion yet.

If you had a way to say "current term" added to "sum of the rest of the stuff", though, you'd be on your way towards a recursive solution.

So what if your function took two parameters: an `n` that says how many terms to write, and a `current_term` variable that gives the current term?

Then you could do this in part of your function:

```
next_term = 10 * current_term + 1
return current_term + sumseries(n-1, next_term);
```

And in fact, that's the core of it:

```
int sumseries(int n, int current_term)
{
    if(n==1)
        return current_term;
    next_term = 10 * current_term + 1
    return current_term + sumseries(n-1, next_term);
}
```

And then change the call in `main` to be `sumseries(n, 1)` instead of just `sumseries(n)`

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int series_sum( unsigned int n )
{
    static unsigned long long int value;
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;

    unsigned long long int sum = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        value = Base *value + 1;
        sum += series_sum( n - 1 ) + value;
        value /= Base;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "series_sum( %u ) = %llu\n", i, series_sum( i ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
series_sum( 0 ) = 0
series_sum( 1 ) = 1
series_sum( 2 ) = 12
series_sum( 3 ) = 123
series_sum( 4 ) = 1234
series_sum( 5 ) = 12345
series_sum( 6 ) = 123456
series_sum( 7 ) = 1234567
series_sum( 8 ) = 12345678
series_sum( 9 ) = 123456789
```

As you see the function has only one parameter as it is required. Also it is better to use the type `unsigned int` as the type of the argument (otherwise you have to check whether the argument is negative) and the type `unsigned long long int` as the return type because the type `int` (or `unsigned int`) is too small to keep the sum.